# Can't hear anything in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I tried with plugged in headphones, without them and with bluetooth headphones. Nothing is heard.

I tried uninstalling and installing again alsa-base and pulseaudio. I also tried reloading alsa. I tried disabling the secure boot. Still I cannot hear anything.

However, the sound card is detected. Here is the output of the lspci command:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Had some problems in the past with audio, but with Ubuntu 18.04. Take a look at system settings > sound:

- If you can see any output device, it might be the output levels. In that case, use alsa-mixer to configure them.
- If you see no output device, you will have to deal with alsa/pulseaudio configuration.

Don´t take it as an expert advice: this is based on my own experience.